# REGEX that leaves one if more than one is present

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have to filter paths they can look like:

- `some_path//rest`
- `some_path/rest`
- `some_path\\\\rest`
- `some_path\rest`

I need to replace some_path//rest with FILTER

- `some_path/rest//` I want `FILTER/`
- `some_path/rest\\` I want `FILTER\`
- `some_path/rest` I want `FILTER`
- `some_path/rest/` I want `FILTER/`
- `some_path/rest\` I want `FILTER\`

I am using `some_path[\\\\\\\/]+rest` to match the middle, if I use it at the end it consumes all the path separators.

I do not know in advance whether the separators will be `/` or `\\` it can mix in a single path.
`some_path/rest\some_more//and/more\\\\more`

Comment: Do you actually want FILTER in all those forms or do you want to rationalise all possible incoming forms to a single output form?

Comment: Any reason you can't use https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath to standardize your path?

Comment: I am testing reports generated by an application across multiple branches so I am forced to filter all possible paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple (without back reference) replace term by using a look ahead.

Use this regex to search:

```
some_path[\\\\/]+rest(?:([\\\\/])(?=\1))?
```

and replace the match with just `'FILTER'`:

```
re.sub(r"some_path[\\\\/]+rest(?:([\\\\/])(?=\1))?", 'FILTER', path)
```

This works by matching (ie consuming) the trailing slash *only* when it is *doubled*.

To allow for when there's no trailing slashes, the match for trailing slashes is made optional by wrapping in `(?:...)?` (which is non-capturing, so the back reference is `\1`, not `\2` which is harder to read).

Note that you don't need quite so many backslashes in your regex.

---

Here's some test code:

```
for path in ('some_path/rest//','some_path/rest\\','some_path/rest','some_path/rest/','some_path/rest\\'):
    print path + ' -> ' + re.sub(r"some_path[\\\\/]+rest(?:([\\\\/])(?=\1))?", 'FILTER', path)
```

Output:

```
some_path/rest// -> FILTER/                                                                                                                                                     
some_path/rest\ -> FILTER\                                                                                                                                                      
some_path/rest -> FILTER                                                                                                                                                        
some_path/rest/ -> FILTER/                                                                                                                                                      
some_path/rest\ -> FILTER\
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using back references. Keep in mind that with Python, you will be seeing the `\` escaped with a second `\` in the output. This example seems to do what you are looking for:

```
>>> for test in ('some_path/rest//','some_path/rest\\','some_path/rest','some_path/rest/','some_path/rest\\'):
...     re.sub(r"some_path[\/]+rest([\/]?)\1*", r"FILTER\1", test)
... 
'FILTER/'
'FILTER\\'
'FILTER'
'FILTER/'
'FILTER\\'
>>>
```

The `\1` is a back reference to the previous `()` group. In the search, it is searching for any number of matches of that item. In the replace, it is just adding in the one item.

Comment: This is not what I need exactly. Per my question I need only one slash forward or backward. And if possible I would rather not add a regex to the replaced value.

Comment: As per the answer, the additional `\` is only the escape of the actual `\`. Try `print re.sub(r"some_path[\/]+rest([\/]?)\1*", r"FILTER\1", test)`, which should show without the extra `\`. re.sub() uses regex as the replace string, but more than that, you're asking for a regex replacement. Your options are either to use a single regex with one backreference, or you could have a multi-step process which breaks the string apart and saves the final delimiter, and then add the pieces back together.